# Ping time spikes randomly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I'm having a little trouble with my wifi network.

There are random spikes in the ping request. These spike to 2800ms.

I have tested the LAN network which doesn't have these spikes.

This just started about a week ago. Before that it never happened.

---

**The following information might also be relevant:**

- No new devices around the house
- Tested it using ConnectBot on my android device, same issue
- Using a router which is connected to a modem.
- Router make and model: TP-Link Archer C2
- Tried changing the channel to 1-6-11 and channel width to 20MHz

[Image of ping request on Windows PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp5jb.png)

Comment: Are these spikes occurring anywhere else other than ping requests using the commandline or similar? Try pinging google or another IP outside your internal network.

Comment: @Leathe Yes, these spikes are also occurring when pinging google.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's interference in the area. You can use Wifi Analyzer on android to track down noise and other wireless signals.

Comment: Everything seems stable on that end